# Symfony does not find mongodb driver (DLL)

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony

I've installed the mongodb driver (`php_mongodb.dll`). The file is inside `xampp\php\ext`. I've used it before with simple connections and queries against my mongodb server and it works perfectly.

To make the connection with mongo I use this simple line:

`$conn = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://localhost:27017");`

However, when I try to use it in my symfony project, I get this error:

> Attempted to load class "Manager" from namespace "AlimentosBundle\Controller\MongoDB\Driver".
>   Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?

I'm very beginner using symfony. Should I import also the DLL inside the symfony project? If not, how could I force Symfony to find the DLL?

I know that doctrine/mongodb bundle actually exists, but I just wanted to try some simple connections, is possible to do it without that bundle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You miss an initial slash. Try this:

```
$conn = new \MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://localhost:27017");
```

instead of:

```
$conn = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://localhost:27017");
```

Obviously, as suggested, you can import the class and use without the namespace, as example:

```
use  MongoDB\Driver\Manager;

...

$conn = Manager("mongodb://localhost:27017");
```

Hope this help

Comment: Right, I just needed to add that initial slash and it worked! Thanks! :D